# Simple horizontal scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

Is it possible to keep a simple function like this here:

```
$.fx.speeds.xslow = 1500;
function goToByScroll(id){
    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#"+id).offset().top
    },'slow');
}
```

and make it for horizontal scrolling?
I want to keep things simple like this without using a big horizontal plugin. I was thinking scrollLeft, but could not get this to work with the offset... Any ideas would be great! Thanks in advance

Comment: The principle for scrolling horizontally is pretty much the same, just operate on the css left: value. Im sure there's lots of tuts on the web.

Comment: yea there is, I just wanted to see this be converted, because it is a clean small code. Thanks anyways

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like you said, you can do this using scrollLeft:

```
function goToByScrollHoriz(id){
    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollLeft: $("#"+id).offset().left
    },'slow');
}
```

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qS2Ke/1/) for a working example (make sure Div #3 isn't visible on the page when you run it).